# Date to Day of the week algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm

What is the algorithm that, given a day, month and year, returns a day of the week?

Comment: On Wikipedia: [Calculating the day of the week](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_the_day_of_the_week).

Comment: You can Google for that in about five seconds. Here is another question on SO about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017745/given-date-get-day-of-week-systemtime

Comment: @darvid: That's a Windows-specific Q&A, I don't think it counts.

Comment: @darvids That question (at least the answers) is about WinAPI and not an algorithm.

Comment: @hammar: Most questions can be answered outside of the site. That's besides the point.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I still think it's reasonable to do a quick search before asking. In this case the first hit on Google turns up an answer.

Comment: @hammar: The [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) says nothing about asking easy questions. If you don't want to answer it, then don't. This isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This can be done using the [`std::mktime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mktime.html) and [`std::localtime`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localtime.html) functions. These functions are not just POSIX, they are mandated by the C++ Standard (C++03 §20.5).

```
#include <ctime>

std::tm time_in = { 0, 0, 0, // second, minute, hour
        4, 9, 1984 - 1900 }; // 1-based day, 0-based month, year since 1900

std::time_t time_temp = std::mktime( & time_in );

// the return value from localtime is a static global - do not call
// this function from more than one thread!
std::tm const *time_out = std::localtime( & time_temp );

std::cout << "I was born on (Sunday = 0) D.O.W. " << time_out->tm_wday << '\n';
```

Comment: +1 upvoted.  Also voted to reopen this question.  Perhaps it is a stack overflow duplicate, I don't know.  But this is a real C++ question (was closed as not a real question), and this is a good answer to it.

Comment: Hmm, got a downvote. Not sure why, but note that `std::localtime` is not thread-safe. See [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7313919/153285).

Comment: I know its accepted answer but not the answer he really asked for.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest algorithm for this is Tomohiko Sakamoto Algorithm:

```
static int t[] = {0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4};
y -= m < 3;
return (y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + t[m-1] + d) % 7;
}
```

Check this out: https://iq.opengenus.org/tomohiko-sakamoto-algorithm/

I found Wang's method also interesting

```
w = (d - d^(m) + y^ - y* + [y^/4 - y*/2] - 2( c mod 4)) mod 7
```

http://rmm.ludus-opuscula.org/PDF_Files/Wang_Day_5_8(3_2015)_high.pdf This pdf is really helpful too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need a starting point.  Today is fine.  Hard-code it.

Then, you need to represent the number of days in a month.  This is 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, ... .  So you can start adding and subtracting 365 % 7 to the day of the week for each year, and (sum of days in difference of month) % 7 again.  And so on.

The caveat:  Leap years occur on every 4th year, but not every 100th, unless that year is also a multiple of 400.

Comment: I can go with that. Hard-coding is totally fine.