# C++11 alternative to localtime_r

Tags: c++, time, c++11, strftime

C++ defines time formatting functions in terms of `strftime`, which requires a `struct tm` "broken-down time" record. However, the C and C++03 languages provide no thread-safe way to obtain such a record; there is just one master `struct tm` for the whole program.

In C++03, this was more or less OK, because the language didn't support multithreading; it merely supported platforms supporting multithreading, which then provided facilities like POSIX [`localtime_r`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/localtime.html).

C++11 also defines new time utilities, which interface with the non-broken-down `time_t` type, which *is* what would be used to reinitialize the global `struct tm`. But obtaining a `time_t` isn't the problem.

Am I missing something or does this task still require reliance on POSIX?

**EDIT:** Here is some workaround code. It maintains compatibility with multithreaded environments that provide `::localtime_r` and single-threaded environments that provide only `std::localtime`. It can easily be adapted to check for other functions as well, such as `posix::localtime_r` or `::localtime_s` or what-have-you.

```
namespace query {
    char localtime_r( ... );

    struct has_localtime_r
        { enum { value = sizeof localtime_r( std::declval< std::time_t * >(), std::declval< std::tm * >() )
                        == sizeof( std::tm * ) }; };


    template< bool available > struct safest_localtime {
        static std::tm *call( std::time_t const *t, std::tm *r )
            { return localtime_r( t, r ); }
    };

    template<> struct safest_localtime< false > {
        static std::tm *call( std::time_t const *t, std::tm *r )
            { return std::localtime( t ); }
    };
}
std::tm *localtime( std::time_t const *t, std::tm *r )
    { return query::safest_localtime< query::has_localtime_r::value >().call( t, r ); }
```

Comment: Can't you just wrap `localtime` in a function that uses a mutex? Or some other lighter-weight form of lock? I don't see how POSIX is required here.

Comment: @Nicol: Yes, but that's only safe as long as nobody else tries to do the same thing. In other words, it works in a program, not in a library.

Comment: But then they'd be calling a non-thread-safe function from threaded code, so they'd get what they deserve. You could just expose a function for them to use, and if they use the standard C one instead, then they get undefined behavior.

Comment: @Nicol: What? I'm writing a library which cannot provide such restrictions to its users.

Comment: You can't tell users not to call non-thread-safe functions in multithreaded code? Or is it that threading is an implementation detail you don't want to expose to your users?

Comment: @Nicol: My library is not multithreaded, but I would like it to be compatible with multithreaded code. Your suggestion to use a mutex guard and call `localtime` anyway is exactly what you're suggesting I tell users not to do. I can't insist that my mutex is *the* mutex for `localtime` — the library's functionality is unrelated. Anyway, anything to do with a mutex will be the wrong solution, since my code is in no way multithreaded, it's only thread-safe.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You're not missing anything.

The next C standard (due out probably this year) does have defined in Annex K:

```
struct tm *localtime_s(const time_t * restrict timer,
                       struct tm * restrict result);
```

And this new function is thread safe!  But don't get too happy.  There's two major problems:

1. `localtime_s` is an **optional** extension to C11.
2. C++11 references C99, not C11.  `local_time_s` is not to be found in C++11, optional or not.

**Update**

In the 4 years since I answered this question, I have also been frustrated by the poor design of C++ tools in this area.  I was motivated to create modern C++ tools to deal with this:

http://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    auto local_time = make_zoned(current_zone(), std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    std::cout << local_time << '\n';
}
```

This just output for me:

2015-10-28 14:17:31.980135 EDT

`local_time` is a pairing of `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` and `time_zone` indicating the local time.

There exists utilities for breaking the `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` into human-readable field types, such as year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and subseconds.  Here is a presentation focusing on those (non-timezone) pieces:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzyGjOm8AKo

All of this is of course thread safe (it is modern C++).

**Update 2**

The above is now part of C++20 with this slightly altered syntax:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    namespace chr = std::chrono;

    chr::zoned_time local_time{chr::current_zone(), chr::system_clock::now()};
    std::cout << local_time << '\n';
}
```

Comment: … And they changed the name! Thanks for the info. It is possible, anyway, to query whether `localtime_r` is available and fall back on `localtime` otherwise. So it looks like I can have my cake and eat it too, after all.

Answer (score 1):

The following answer pointed out a key detail of `mktime()` (which is the only thread-safe function handling `struct tm` even before C99):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54248414/103167

Here then is a portable alternative to `localtime_r` or `localtime_s`:

```
//  localtime_s(&startTm, &startTimeT);
tm startTm{};
startTm.tm_isdst = -1;
startTm.tm_year = 122;
auto refTimeT = mktime(&startTm);

// goes horribly out of range but ok because mktime will canonicalize
startTm.tm_sec += startTimeT - refTimeT;

mktime(&startTm);
```