# SFINAE: checking the existence of a function breaks when the overload is moved to other namespaces

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, sfinae, overload-resolution

I want to check for the existence of a function in a specific namespace using SFINAE. I have found [SFINAE to test a free function from another namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756779/sfinae-to-test-a-free-function-from-another-namespace) which does the job, but there are some things I don't understand.

Currently I have this working code, straight from the linked question:

```
// switch to 0 to test the other case
#define ENABLE_FOO_BAR 1

namespace foo {
  #if ENABLE_FOO_BAR
    int bar();
  #endif
}

namespace detail_overload {
  template<typename... Args> void bar(Args&&...);
}
namespace detail {
  using namespace detail_overload;
  using namespace foo;
  template<typename T> decltype(bar()) test(T);
  template<typename> void test(...);
}
static constexpr bool has_foo_bar = std::is_same<decltype(detail::test<int>(0)), int>::value;

static_assert(has_foo_bar == ENABLE_FOO_BAR, "something went wrong");
```

(the `ENABLE_FOO_BAR` macro is just for testing purpose, in my real code I don't have such a macro available otherwise I wouldn't be using SFINAE)

---

However, as soon as I put `detail_overload::bar()` in any other namespace (adjusting the `using` directive as needed), the detection breaks silently and the `static_assert` kicks in **when `foo::bar()` exists**. It only works when the "dummy" `bar()` overload is directly in the global namespace, or part of the `::detail_overload` namespace (note the global `::` scope).

```
// breaks
namespace feature_test {
  namespace detail_overload {
    template<typename... Args> void bar(Args&&...);
  }
  namespace detail {
    using namespace detail_overload;
    using namespace foo;
    //...

// breaks
namespace feature_test {
  template<typename... Args> void bar(Args&&...);
  namespace detail {
    using namespace foo;
    //...

// breaks
namespace detail {
  namespace detail_overload {
    template<typename... Args> void bar(Args&&...);
  }
  using namespace detail_overload;
  using namespace foo;
  //...

// works
template<typename... Args> void bar(Args&&...);
namespace feature_test {
  namespace detail {
    using namespace foo;
    //...

// works
namespace detail_overload {
  template<typename... Args> void bar(Args&&...);
}
namespace feature_test {
  namespace detail {
    using namespace detail_overload;
    using namespace foo;
    //...
```

I realize this is the very same problem as the question I linked to, and as mentioned I already have a working solution, but what is not addressed there is **why *precisely* does this happen?**

As a side question, is there any way to achieve correct SFINAE detection without polluting the global namespace with either `bar()` or a `detail_overload` namespace? As you can guess from the non-working examples, I'd like to neatly wrap everything in a single `feature_test` namespace.

Comment: `detail::test(0)`: for the second overload of `test`, the template parameter cannot be deduced (so it can never be selected). Try `detail::test<int>(0)`.

Comment: @DyP changed the call to `detail::test<int>(0)`, no luck: the `static_assert` still kicks in when `foo::bar()` exists and the "dummy" overload is somewhere else than `::bar()` or `::detail_overload::bar()`.

Comment: [namespace.udir]/2 "During unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), the names appear as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the *using-directive* and the
nominated namespace." So they appear in different namespaces, and name hiding occurs.

Comment: @DyP Damn, that's quite obvious in hindsight. So I guess there's no way to avoid polluting the global namespace. Injecting the `detail_overload` namespace into `foo` (and then `using namespace foo::detail_overload;`) indeed works but since I don't own `foo` it'd be quite a cavalier thing to do, to say the least. Anyway, care to make an answer of your latest comment, since it explains the problem I was facing?

Comment: If your function `bar` took any arguments, you could make use of dependent name lookup to make it work (w/o a second overload of `bar`).

Comment: @DyP Indeed, dependent name lookup works like a charm (`bar` *does* take arguments in my real code). Thanks again! For what it's worth I posted an answer with the code modified as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll change it slightly so the fall-back declaration of `bar` isn't a template (= shorter code), and don't use SFINAE as this is purely a name lookup issue.

```
namespace foo {
    int bar(int);
}

namespace feature_test {
    namespace detail_overload {
        void bar(...);
    }

    namespace detail {
        using namespace detail_overload;
        using namespace foo;

        void test() { bar(0); } // (A)
    }
}
```

In line (A), the compiler needs to find the name `bar`. How is it looked up? It's not argument-dependent, so it must be unqualified lookup: [basic.lookup.unqual]/2

> The declarations from the namespace nominated by a *using-directive* become visible in a namespace enclosing the using-directive; see 7.3.4. For the purpose of the unqualified name lookup rules described in 3.4.1, the declarations from the namespace nominated by the *using-directive* are considered members of that enclosing namespace.

Note they become in **an enclosing** namespace, not **the** enclosing namespace. The details from [namespace.udir]/2 reveal the issue:

> [...] During unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), the names appear as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the *using-directive* and the nominated namespace.

That is, for the name lookup of `bar` inside `test`:

```
namespace foo {
    int bar(int);
}

// as if
using foo::bar;
namespace feature_test {
    namespace detail_overload {
        void bar(...);
    }

    // as if
    using detail_overload::bar;
    namespace detail {
        // resolved
        // using namespace detail_overload;
        // using namespace foo;

        void test() { bar(0); } // (A)
    }
}
```

Therefore, the name `bar` found in `feature_test` hides the name (not) found in the global scope.

*Note:* Maybe you can hack around this issue with argument-dependent name lookup (and a second SFINAE). If something comes to my mind, I'll add it.

Comment: *Pedantic note:* Technically, it's argument-dependent name lookup, where the sets of associated namespaces and classes are empty. ADL uses unqualified lookup, and in this case, it effectively falls back to unqualified lookup.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Indeed the SFINAE part got me confused and I didn't see it was "just" a name lookup issue.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to DyP's answer and following his comment:

> If your function `bar` took any arguments, you could make use of dependent name lookup to make it work (w/o a second overload of `bar`).

Indeed in my real code `bar()` *does* take arguments.

> As a side question, is there any way to achieve correct SFINAE detection without polluting the global namespace...

So yes, dependent name lookup works like a charm. For the sake of completeness, and in case it can help others in the future, here's my now perfectly working code:

```
#define ENABLE_FOO_BAR 1

namespace foo {
  #if ENABLE_FOO_BAR
    int bar(int);
  #endif
}

namespace feature_test {
  namespace detail {
    using namespace foo;
    template<typename T> decltype(bar(std::declval<T>())) test(int);
    template<typename> void test(...);
  }
  static constexpr bool has_foo_bar = std::is_same<decltype(detail::test<int>(0)), int>::value;
  static_assert(has_foo_bar == ENABLE_FOO_BAR, "something went wrong");
}
```

All credit goes to [DyP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/420683/dyp), I don't believe I'd have thought about this by myself.