# Check if template method exists without relying on automated template deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

Is it possible to write a tester if a template-method with a given signature is defined?

The method is of following signature:

```
template<typename ReturnType>
ReturnType get(std::string) { return std::declval<ReturnType>(); }
```

I searched here but all I found were mechanism relying on automated template deduction 
 (e.g. [How to test if template function exists at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31605368/how-to-test-if-template-function-exists-at-compile-time))

Comment: "but all I found were mechanism relying on automated template deduction" - why don't you just use them?

Comment: how would I? Automated template deduction doesn't work in my example because no parameter of the method is of the required Type

Comment: To clarify: do you want a method to test whether `template <typename> get(std::string)` exists, or whether a particular specialization `get<T>(std::string)` can be called?

Comment: Off topic: you can use `std::declval()` inside a `decltype()`, not in a body of a function.

Comment: _is defined?_: Does it mean: Is template existing? Is template instanced for this type? Is a function with this signature available (which is not necessarily a template)? Why (for what) do you need this?

Comment: @lisyarus The second
@ Scheff The helper should return true if a function of the signature in my post is defined. It's for better readable error-messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
constexpr bool test() { return is_invocable<decltype(get<T>), std::string>::value; }
```

See [std::is_invocable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable). However, `test<T>` still does not compile if `get<T>` does not; see comments below.

Comment: Didn't know of this. Most SFINAE stuff documented here is pre c++17; thank you

Comment: The first argument to `std::is_invocable` is a type, but `get<T>` is not a type: https://wandbox.org/permlink/ySByqAzEuAnxJsRr

Comment: @lisyarus It seems a `decltype()` fixes the suggested solution: [Fixed Demo on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qJNzdwpPIUCpKqsk).

Comment: @Scheff It fails to distinguish between defined & undefined specializations, thus simply checking if `template <typename> get (std::string)` exists, which (in my opinion) looks somewhat useless: https://wandbox.org/permlink/FGIlr3lVocP5bFin

Comment: @lisyarus I agree. That's why my comment how _defined_ is meant precisely... (The example is somehow a bit like Schroedingers Cat: As soon as you check the template it is instanced and hence exists.) ;-)

Comment: @lisyarus Though, "exists" doesn't describe it exactly... [Above Code on godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/DefbhU)

Comment: @Scheff Checking godbolt is a hack: compiler optimizations can remove a lot. Anyways, I was too sloppy in my previous comment. There is no such thing as mere *existence* for C++ functions, whether template or not: they can be *declared* and *defined* (and *specialized*, for what it's worth). In our case, the proposed solution checks if `get<T>` was *declared*.

Comment: @user3520616 if you remove the "accepted" I can delete the solution which is not correct.

Comment: @francesco Why not simply fix it (even if the result is of questionable worth)? At least, you teached two people about the existance of `std::is_invocable()`: the OP and me. ;-)

Comment: @Scheff see the correction, and thanks for the fix!

Comment: @francesco This still won't compile: you should either declare a template variable via `constexpr bool test = ...`, or declare a constexpr function like `constexpr bool test() { return ... }`. The current version is something in between.