# Using one or more namespaces when conflicting symbols are present?

Tags: c++, namespaces

What are the pro and cons of using two namespaces such as

```
namespace library1
{
  void function1();
}

namespace library1_sublibrary1
{
  void function1();
}
```

instead of

```
namespace library1
{
  void function1();

  namespace sublibrary1
  {
    void function1();
  }
}
```

I would have to fully qualify symbols in the second case, right? Is there any concrete reason (beyond personal taste) why one should be preferred on the other?

Comment: you could use an alias for the nested namespace: `namespace nested = library1::sublibrary1;`. This would safe a couple of types :)

Comment: Besides the personal taste, if `sublibrary1` is in fact a part of `library1` it just seems more logical (to me, oops, there's that personal taste) to structure it the second way. And as a general hint, avoid `using` to pull in whole namespaces into the global namespace.

Comment: There are differences in unqualified name lookup inside those sublibrary1 namespaces. You cannot stop unqualified lookup from finding global scope declarations in the first case via a *using-declaration*. If you use ADL, you don't have to fully qualify names of functions that take arguments of types declared in the namespace of the function.

Comment: I'm interested in this DyP, what is ADL and why in the first case an unqualified lookup would be confused?

Comment: @DavidKernin (I almost overlooked your response; please prepend the username with `@` to send a notification.) ADL is argument-dependent lookup. When you write `function1(some_argument);`, the name `function1` has to be found, and argument-dependent lookup also searches the namespaces associated with the argument(s). [Here's an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c541a3c31185cf32) of what I meant in the previous comment.

Comment: Thanks, make that an answer and I'll mark it. It's enough for my purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating from two comments.

Between the two versions (one: two separate namespaces, two: nested namespaces), there are some differences in name lookup. Most of these can be overcome with either a *using-declaration* (e.g. `using outer::function0;`) or a *using-directive* (e.g. `using namespace library1;`), but some cannot.

#### 1. unqualified lookup inside the inner namespace

```
#include <iostream>

namespace outer
{
    void function0() { std::cout << "outer::function0" << std::endl; }

    namespace inner
    {
        void test0()
        {
            function0(); // finds outer::function
        }
    }
}

namespace another_outer
{
    void test0_1()
    {
        // either
        using namespace outer;
        // or
        using outer::function0;

        function0();
    }
}
```

N.B. you can also put the *using-directive* or *using-declaration* at namespace scope in `another_outer`, but some difference remains:

#### 2. stopping unqualified lookup

Unqualified lookup stops in a scope once a name has been found (and then doesn't search the outer scopes). This can be used to hide functions from other scopes. Here's an example of a problem related to this; also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18934399/420683).

```
void function1() { std::cout << "::function1" << std::endl; }

namespace another_outer
{
    void function1() { std::cout << "another_outer::function1" << std::endl; }
}

namespace outer
{
    namespace inner
    {
        void function1() { std::cout << "outer::inner::function1" << std::endl; }
    }

    void test1()
    {
        function1(); // finds ::function1

        {
            using namespace inner;
            function1(); // finds (only) outer::inner::function1
        }

        {
            using namespace another_outer;
            //function1(); // finds both ::function1 and another_outer::function1
            // error: ambiguous call
        }
    }
}
```

#### 3. ADL

This isn't about differences between the two variants, but addresses "I would have to fully qualify symbols in the second case, right?".
Argument-dependent lookup happens when you don't qualify the name of a function in a function call. It looks for the name of the function in namespaces (and classes) associated with the arguments.

```
namespace outer
{
    struct ADL {};
    void function2(ADL&) { std::cout << "outer::function2" << std::endl; }

    namespace inner
    {
        void function2(ADL const&);
        void test2()
        {
            ADL x;
            function2(x); // finds both outer::function2
                          // and outer::inner::function2
            // overload resolution selects outer::function2
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    outer::ADL x;
    function2(x); // finds outer::function2
    outer::inner::test2();

    // other tests:
    outer::inner::test0();
    outer::test1();
}
```

#### 4. Specifically about conflicting symbols

If you have two identical functions (except for the return type) in `outer` and `outer::inner` and both are found for some call, that call will be ambiguous. But unqualified lookup might only find one of them:

```
namespace outer
{
    void function3() { std::cout << "outer::function3()" << std::endl; }

    namespace inner
    {
        void function3()
        { std::cout << "outer::inner::function3()" << std::endl; }

        void test3()
        {
            function3(); // only finds outer::inner::function3
        }
    }

    void test3_1()
    {
        using namespace inner;
        //function3(); // finds both outer::function3
                       // and outer::inner::function3
        // error: ambiguous call

        using inner::function3;
        function3(); // finds (only) outer::inner::function3
    }
}

namespace another_outer
{
    void function3() { std::cout << "another_outer::function3" << std::endl; }

    void test3_1()
    {
        using namespace outer;
        function3(); // still only finds another_outer::function3

        using outer::function3;
        function3(); // only finds outer::function3
    }
}
```