# Template meta-programming: checking for existence of a function defined later

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm solving a classical problem: check if there exists a free function in some namespace. It is discussed, e.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933857/sfinae-checking-the-existence-of-a-function-breaks-when-the-overload-is-moved-t).

However, there is a slight twist: the definition of the function may appear *later* than the checker class. Here is an example.

```
struct Yes {};
struct No {};
struct YesButLater {};

void f(Yes) {}

template<typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct HasF : public std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct HasF<T, decltype(void( ::f(T()) ))> : public std::true_type {};

void f(YesButLater) {}

int main() {
    cout << HasF<Yes>::value << endl; // 1
    cout << HasF<No>::value << endl; // 0
    cout << HasF<YesButLater>::value << endl; // 0, expected 1
}
```

`f(YesButLater)` is declared later than `HasF` helper class, and, although I instantiate the template after `f(YesButLater)` was defined, the helper doesn't notice it.

So, here is question 1: how can I deal with it?

Now one more, more curious, example.

```
template<typename T>
struct HasF<T, decltype(void( f(T()) ))> : public std::true_type {};

void f(YesButLater) {}
void f(std::string) {}

int main() {
    cout << HasF<YesButLater>::value << endl; // 1 (but what's the difference?)
    cout << HasF<std::string>::value << endl; // 0, expected 1
}
```

Note that I removed `::` from the `decltype(...)` expression. Now for some reason `f(YesButLater)` **is noticed** by `HasF`, but `f(std::string)` still remains obscure.

Question 2: Why do we observe different behaviour for `::f(T())` and `f(T())` in this example? Moreover, what is the difference between `YesButLater` and `std::string`?

I think that there is some trick with namespace lookup but I cannot get the thing.

Comment: my guess - it is due to [adl](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) rules...

Comment: @W.F. Yes, probably, though I still don't understand why :: matters as I always use global namespace in the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I've figured out what is going on.

When I write `::f(...)`, the name `f` is being searched with a *qualified name lookup*. This kind of lookup encounters only names which declarations were available up to the point of call. Now it is clear why the first version couldn't find `f(YesButLater)`: its declaration occurs later.

When I write `f(...)`, *unqualified name lookup* happens. Again, it fails to find any name which was declared before calling point. Here *argument dependent lookup* comes up. It searches for `f(T)` in the *whole* namespace which `T` belongs to. In case of `f(YesButLater)` this namespace is global, hence the function is found. In case of `f(std::string)` ADL tries searches for `std::f(std::string)` and, of course, fails.

Here are two examples to illustrate the case.

```
namespace foo {
    class C {};
}

template<typename T>
void call() {
    f(T());
}

namespace foo {
    void f(C) {}
}

int main() {
    call<foo::C>();
}
```

Here `f(T())` is being searched with ADL and is found, although its declaration is after `call()`. And if we modify the `call()` function...

```
template<typename T>
void call() {
    foo::f(T());
}
```

This results in compilation error because `foo::f(T)` performs qualified lookup and cannot find the needed function as no declaration is available at the moment.