# Day of the week from a given date

Tags: c++, c, datetime

I need to find the weekday from the given date; I have following code but does not work

```
int day;
char *str ="25/02/2014";  
struct tm tm;

if (strptime(str, "%d/%m/%Y", &tm) != NULL)
{
    time_t t = mktime(&tm);
    day = localtime(&t)->tm_wday;
    return day;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797814/date-to-day-of-the-week-algorithm

Comment: Does this compile ? Here it doesn't unless you replace `struct tm  *tm;` by `struct tm tm;`

Comment: Even after changing struct tm tm ; the result of weekday is not good .The result of day is always 4 ("27/02/2014")

Comment: I reran this with `struct tm * tm;` but removed the `&` from every `&tm`, and I'm getting results: 4 for 27/02/2014, and 2 for 25/02/2014.

Comment: if you use `struct tm *tm` and you don't initialize to `NULL` then `tm` points to some invalid address and when the address of that invalid memory location you are passing to `strptime` it fills that memory with data. In this case the behavior will be undefined.

Comment: @rajenpandit: with `struct tm *tm = NULL` it will crash also because NULL is also an invalid address.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: as per `@Saviour Self` the code is returning the  expected result by using `struct tm *tm`. It is happening because `tm` is not initialized with `NULL` otherwise program would have crashed.

Comment: @rajenpandit: ok, so it just runs because he is lucky.

Comment: After assigining `struct tm tm = {0};` the program gave me correct result

Answer (score 2):

You should take `struct tm  tm;` instead of `struct tm * tm;`

you need to initialize `tm`   by using      `memset(&tm,0x00,sizeof(tm));` otherwise `mktime` will return -1

Comment: With `memset(&tm, 0, sizeof tm)`, is not `isdst` field better set to -1 than left at 0?  (I suppose it makes little difference though as DST changes at midnight (h:m:s == 0:00:00) are rare.)

Answer (score 0):

The result `4` for the date 27/02/2014 is correct, see [`time.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/time.h.html)

> **Description**
>   ...
>   int    tm_wday  Day of week [0,6] (Sunday =0).

Sunday is 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2, Wednesday = 3 and *Thursday = 4*, ...