# C++ Chrono determine whether day is a weekend?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

I have a date in the form year (int), month (int) and day (int), for example, 2018, 10, 12 for October 12th, 2018.

Is there a way I can use C++ Chrono library with these integers to determine whether my "date" is a weekend day?

If not, what would be the simplest alternative way to achieve this?

Comment: If you know that October 12, 2018 is a Friday, can't you simply calculate the offset in days from October 13 (sat) and see if it is a multiple of 7 or a multiple of 7 + 1?

Comment: Do you need this to be locale-aware? Rest days differ around the world.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date to Day of the week algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797814/date-to-day-of-the-week-algorithm)

Comment: Wow, this seems to be surprisingly difficult. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0355r3.html would make it easier.

Comment: @BasinhetVeld I was just using today as an example to explain my input data. I am looking at dates I do not know what day of the week they are.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I just need to know given year, month, day whether it was a Saturday or Sunday, so not locale aware.

Comment: I was putting together a quick solution and gave up. It's hard enough to create a timepoint with the new tools, but getting calendar properties of it back out appears nigh impossible. Can you just do mktime then gmtime back again or something? It's not chrono but it's standard ... unless you want the safe version of gmtime of course. Ugh.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Boost Datetime Gregorian is the answer :)

Comment: @mezamorphic Possibly - sadly DateTime is heavy (and requires build&link!) so Bas's arithmetic solution (combined with a mktime step) is probably what I'd do.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry I don't follow? The Boost solution is three lines of code. I'm really surprised nobody mentioned it.

Comment: This [date](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) library is up for standardization: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date

Comment: std::chrono does not provide calenar services. The boost solution is fine if you happen to have boost around and don't mind its non-trivial footprint.

Comment: @mezamorphic The code part of it is great but the logistics are not, unless you're already using DateTime in your project, by comparison with the arithmetic method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++20, you will be able to do this:

```
#include <chrono>

constexpr
bool
is_weekend(std::chrono::sys_days t)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    const weekday wd{t};
    return wd == Saturday || wd == Sunday;
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    static_assert(!is_weekend(year{2018}/10/12), "");
    static_assert( is_weekend(year{2018}/10/13), "");
}
```

Naturally if the input isn't `constexpr`, then the computation can't be either.

No one that I'm aware of is yet shipping this, however you can get a head start with this syntax using [Howard Hinnant's datetime lib](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  You just need to `#include "date/date.h"` and change a few `using namespace std::chrono;` to `using namespace date;`.

```
#include "date/date.h"

constexpr
bool
is_weekend(date::sys_days t)
{
    using namespace date;
    const weekday wd{t};
    return wd == Saturday || wd == Sunday;
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    static_assert(!is_weekend(year{2018}/10/12), "");
    static_assert( is_weekend(year{2018}/10/13), "");
}
```

This will work with C++17, C++14, and if you remove the `constexpr`, C++11.  It won't port to earlier than C++11 as it does depend on `<chrono>`.

For bonus points, the above function will also work with the current time (UTC):

```
    assert(!is_weekend(floor<days>(std::chrono::system_clock::now())));
```

Comment: Can you clarify what part of this is C++20 specific? Just the `/` operator? The `weekday` part?

Comment: Pretty much everything is C++20 specific:  `sys_days`, `weekday`, `Saturday`, `Sunday`, `year`, the `operator/()`.

Comment: "For bonus points, the above function will also work with the current time" I don't think this is quite correct—you'd need to [offset the current timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76561402/how-to-find-the-current-weekday-with-stdchrono/76561589#76561589) before you `floor<days>()` and wouldn't be able to pass the resulting `local_time` directly to the `sys_days`

Comment: "current time **(UTC)**".

Comment: For the current _local_ `weekday`, see [this good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76561589/576911) (which I've upvoted).  ;-)